# add Context menu in object explorer for SSMS 2016

Tags: c#, ssms-2016

Im trying to rewrite our addin for SSMS 2014 to an extension for SSMS 2016.

I can't seem to find a way to add a menu or command to the context menu of the object explorer.

On the Microsoft website I can find lots of id's for all the windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118.aspx)
but not for the object explorer (object browser is a different window)

For the solution explorer I can use the following in the vsct file:

```
&lt;Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_SOLNNODE"/&gt;
```

Can anyone tell me the id for the object explorer context menu?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
private IObjectExplorerService explorerService;
private List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
// init
explorerService = DteServices.GetService<IObjectExplorerService>(dte);
//
explorerService.GetSelectedNodes(out nodeCount, out nodes);
INodeInformation node = nodes[0];
IMenuHandler menuHandler = node.GetService(typeof(IMenuHandler)) as IMenuHandler;
MethodInfo addChildMethod = menuHandler.GetType().GetMethod("AddChild");

for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.Count; i++)
  addChildMethod.Invoke(menuHandler, new object[] { string.Empty, menuItems[i] });
```

DteServices - it's our internal class.
Please check MSDN [How to: Get a Service from the DTE Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166401.aspx)

Comment: what is "ServiceManager"? in which dll does it exists? it would help me tremendously

Comment: @user2033402 sorry, it's our internal class. We use it to get DTE services